Fixing the screen on a new toyota rav4 XLE SUV
I'm asking this question for someone.
The person who is driving this car noticed that the electronic screen next to the speedometer is now showing a menu of options which she believes is an abnormal screen for normal driving operations. She asked me to figure out how to return the screen back to the home screen and I couldn't even figure it out myself despite me knowing computers. I tried the arrows, the circle, and some other buttons and I couldn't figure it out.
I just want the home screen back so she feels more confident in her driving because if the wrong settings are applied, she could end up in an accident.
UPDATE:
I added some pictures that shows some controls and the rectangular screen showing what she says is the problem screen.






Welcome! A photo of the screen would add clarity to the question.

Did you Refer to the Fine Manual?

I was looking through the manual that came with the car and it was all confusing to me.

Also, what year is the RAV4? Might be different between years for behavior as well as equipment.

You and the owner can review the owner's manual carefully to learn how to navigate electronic controls, search online for videos from Toyota representatives explaining the nuances of electronics, find someone familiar with Toyotas or visit the dealer.
I went from a 21yr old car to a new one and surprisingly, the dealer explained almost everything I didn't know before letting me drive out. I don't expect many dealers doing this but it helped me.

I added some photos. hopefully someone can shed some light.

The round button on the right of the steering wheel - use the left/right buttons to change to a different menu series. Up/down will move within the menu (such as the one shown) or up/down to different screens under that menu series.

I did try that idea but that didn't help. I'm trying to reach whatever the home screen is which the car owner can't seem to describe herself
